# Using Spock framework with Groovy 2.6+ to support Java 8+ syntax

Tags: java, spring, gradle, groovy, spock

I have a Java library compiled using JDK 9 syntax. But, I am using `spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4`, Which does not support JDK 8+ syntax. So, in my Java code, I can use lambdas, default methods, and method references. But, in my tests I cannot. I have to use a clunky workaround for lambdas where I write a Groovy closure, then cast it to a `Function<...>` using the `as` keyword. But, other syntax such as method references like `Class::method` simply will not compile. Below is the dependencies section of my `build.gradle`.

How can I upgrade it such that I am using a newer version of Groovy that supports newer versions of Java?

All of there documentation seems to be out of date, and only references up to Groovy 2.4.

```
dependencies {
  testCompile(
    'junit:junit:4.12',
    'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4',
    'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4',
    'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.1.RELEASE',
    'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2',
    'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.1'
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried referencing the version you prefer (and excluding it from spock if needed)?

Comment: @cfrick You mean, just typing it in, like changing the line to `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.6.0`? The problem is that the following lines specify the groovy version as well (they should match as far as I know) and once I change the spock version, it tells me that there is no spock library define for that version. But, I just cant accept that this many years have passed and there is no way to incorporate Java 8 syntax. Im just missing something

Comment: You can use `org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.4-SNAPSHOT` which is not locked to groovy-2.4 so you should be able to use groovy 2.6 or 3, just note that those are alpha versions and spock is not tested with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when working with Spock 1.2-groovy-2.4-SNAPSHOT and Groovy 3.0.0-alpha-1 you cannot directly use Java's lambda and method reference syntax, I just tested it in my sample Spock/Geb Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA. But even with Spock 1.1 and Groovy 2.4.7 it it quite simple and elegant to replace lambdas and method references without casting or `as`, as far as I saw in my quick test:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import groovy.transform.ToString
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
import spock.lang.Specification

class LambdaMethodRefTest extends Specification {

  def "Replace lambdas and method references in Groovy"() {
    given:
    def bookStream = [
      new Book("Fortran", "Fred", 1957, 57.99),
      new Book("Java in 3 Days", "Alice", 2005, 11.99),
      new Book("Java in 4 Days", "Bob", 2005, 22.99),
      new Book("Filter-Map-Reduce with Lambdas", "Claire", 2014, 33.99)
    ].stream()

    when:
    def mapReduceResult = bookStream
      .filter { it.year >= 2004 }
      .peek(System.out.&println)
      .map { it.author }
      .map { it.toUpperCase() }
      .peek { System.out.println(it) }
      .reduce("", { s1, s2 -> (s1.isEmpty()) ? s2 : s1 + ", " + s2 })

    then:
    mapReduceResult == "ALICE, BOB, CLAIRE"
  }

  @TupleConstructor
  @ToString(includeNames = true, includePackage = false)
  static class Book {
    String title, author; int year; double price
  }

}
```

Please notice the two different ways of calling `System.out.println` - your choice. ;-)

Console log:

```
LambdaMethodRefTest$Book(title:Java in 3 Days, author:Alice, year:2005, price:11.99)
ALICE
LambdaMethodRefTest$Book(title:Java in 4 Days, author:Bob, year:2005, price:22.99)
BOB
LambdaMethodRefTest$Book(title:Filter-Map-Reduce with Lambdas, author:Claire, year:2014, price:33.99)
CLAIRE
```

What exactly are you missing?

---

**Update:** Somehow my old code using `.map(String.&toUpperCase)` is not working anymore after I changed some things in my Maven project. I wonder why it ever worked before. So I have updated the sample code.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Just one question. Idk Groovy well, but why are you using `{i -> System.out&.println(i)}` when `{ i -> System.out.println(i)}` also works? And, How come method references do not work? `{System.out::println}` using "::" syntax? That's my issue, I was used to using method references for simple one-liners, but in Groovy that causes a syntax error.

Comment: Where did you see `{i -> System.out&.println(i)}`? I never wrote that. I just wrote `System.out.&println`, that is the method reference you complained about not working. It does work, just Groovy syntax, not Java 8. While the former is a method reference based on an object instance (`System.out`), `String.&toUpperCase` is an example for one without an instance.

Comment: Thank you, I was unclear on what syntax that was. I didn't know what the & was for. Perhaps I just need to learn some of subtle differences. But, my method references work now thanks to your answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: Please note: I have just updated the sample code and explanation a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed in 2020. Spock supports Groovy 3 (which supports Java 8+ enhancements, including lambda expression) starting with version [2.0-M2](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M2/release_notes.html).

For Gradle it should be enough to add a Spock's JAR dedicated for Groovy 3:

```
testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M2-groovy-3.0')
```

and enable JUnit Platform:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Btw, as a person who developed support for Groovy 3 in Spock I gathered various aspects (including caveats) relating migration from Spock 1.3 to 2.0 in a [blog post](https://blog.solidsoft.info/2020/01/02/migrating-spock-1-3-tests-to-spock-2-0/) - it might be worth to read it :-).